# How to handle multilingual data in lettuce?

Tags: localization, cucumber, gherkin, persian, lettuce

I wrote a *.feature file and step.py with lettuce that work correctly, but when I put Persian data into *.feature file, it stops working.

This is my feature file:

```
Feature: Computefactorial
In order to play with Lettuce
As beginners
We'll implement factorial

Scenario: Factorial of 0
    Given I have the number 0
    When I compute its factorial
    Then I see the number علی
```

and this is my step.py:

```
from lettuce import *

@step('I have the number (\d+)')
def have_the_number(step, number):
    world.number = int(number)

@step('I compute its factorial')
def compute_its_factorial(step):
    world.number = factorial(world.number)

@step('I see the number (\w+)')
def check_number(step, expected):
    #expected = int(expected)
    assert True

def factorial(number):
    return -1
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Is not a number علی. Surround it with "". And in the step file, try the same, surround (\w+) with ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for answers.
i solve this problem with using

`@step('I see the number ([\s|\S]*)')`

this work good and accept spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a `string` you need *quotation marks*. The feature file should look like this.

```
Scenario: Factorial of 0
    Given I have the number 0
    When I compute its factorial
    Then I see the number "علی"
```

and in the step file:

```
...
@step('I see the number "(\w+)"')
def check_number(step, expected):
    #expected = int(expected)
    assert True
...
```

Hope it helps. Step definition using a string is on the main page of the [documentation](http://lettuce.it/index.html)